# Should i use normal tag when i am using style component?

Tags: reactjs, components, styles, styled-components

As I mentioned in the title, Do I should use a normal tag html when i am using Style Component?
For example:

My div is styled in Styled Component and if I have a p tag inside it, should i styled this p tag as well?
or i can just have a normal tag and 'style component tag'

Answer (score 4):

I sometimes mix both. For example,

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Box = styled.div `
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2rem;

  h3 {
    color: orange;
  }

  p {
    color: white;
  }
`

export const InfoBox = () => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <h3>Information</h3>
      <p>An example of paragraph text</p>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

In this example `<h3>` and `<p>` are both normal html tags, whilst `<Box>` is a styled component. And as you can also see in this example, the `<h3>` and `<p>` tags can still be styled with css (as long as they are children of `<Box>`).

Answer (score 0):

With `styled-components` you are basically styling only a single html element or react component at a time.

```
const StyledDiv = styled.div``;
const StyledMyComponent = styled(MyComponent)``;
```

This creates and returns a react component. Every react component has an implicit `children` prop, so you use your `StyledDiv` to wrap *any* other element in JSX, it doesn't really matter much.

```
<StyledDiv>
  <p>This is my p-tag text wrapped in my styled div-tag</p>
  <StyledP>This is my styled p-tag text wrapped in my styled div-tag</StyledP>
</StyledDiv>
```

You only need style a `<p>` if you need it to be styled, otherwise it doesn't matter since the child element/component can be any valid JSX element.

Comment: What's your opinion on more complex components, say button. They come with a tons of annoying default so you seldom want an unstyled button tag. So you think in this case I should always prefer a component? To avoid having both styled components and global style it's maybe better to use a styled component systematically?

Comment: @EricBurel This is what you can use the [.attrs](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs) for, to set/specify prop values passed in to the component. The rest of your comment I don't quite follow.

Comment: For instance I need an "unstyled" button. I already have global style for "button" component, but I also have a Button component (that's some old code, I hadn't decided between styled components and normal tags at the time of writing ^^). I hesitate between further improving style for the button tag, or further improving by Button styled component. But I think I'll go for the styled component path.

Comment: @EricBurel I would. Using CSS-in-JS has become pretty standard in a lot of UI/frontend libraries.